# How do you hide an element using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, hide

I have met a problem with the .hide function in jquery.

My code is below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myDiv").hide
})
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You forgot to invoke the function. To invoke functions, you need to put `()`s after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's [.hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mydiv").hide()
})

  $(".show").click(function(){
    $("#mydiv").show();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mydiv">This is a div.</div>


<button class="show">Show</button>
```